# how to grow admob income

Tags: android, admob

I'm developping an App by my own (android only) and after 1 month on google play i grew the daily active users base from 100 to around 300 users.

The user avarage engagement kept around 15 minutes/day (those data come from firebase dashboard)

But on last days my admob revenue reduced to lower than half

I have 2 adunits in this app: 1 for a banner, 1 for video reward

During the whole month the banner got around 0.25 and video reward around 1.90USD RPM

all this changed to 0.11 and 1.11USD RPM respectivelly

Although the user growing happened slowly during the month... the admob revenue dropped at once, from one day to another
[image]

There was absolutelly no change in app that could explain this, the only thing that happened was I added some in-app products (and made few sales) and I connected the admob app with the play store link (I still dont know what is the point of that the only change i saw was the admob page now shows the icon of my app)

I sent some support requests to several google products all of them came with very stupid and generic responses most of all suggesting i should run an ad campaing to grow my user base

I was able to grew the user base during the month thanks to an ad campaing (ran out of google companies)

I made one spreadsheet with data from admob and firebase if someone can look the data and give me some insights

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ta8m2kfyxs0wcbx/problema.xlsx?dl=0

I really need help, on top of my mind the only thing I can think about this problem is like google has some kind of "special support" to micro apps in order to motivate them keep developing, once i reached the score to be classified as "small app" google removed any benefit or even injected some dificulties in order to force me use their services to keep growing

Comment: Hi Rafael, did you get a solution for this? I've noticed that this year as of March, my RPM dropped by 30%, resulting in a 30% drop in my Adsense revenue.